# For loop output to a string in qt

Tags: string, qt, for-loop, ascii

the problem is i want my output as a usable like string.

Code:

```
string message = "ASD";

qDebug() << "Message in ASCII Dec : ";
for(int i=0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    cout << (int)message.at(i) << "";

}
```

Output:

```
658368
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string that contain 658368, use this :

```
#include <QString>
QString displayString(){
    std::string message = "ASD";
    QString result;

    qDebug() << "Message in ASCII Dec : ";
    for(int i=0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << (int)message.at(i) << "";
        result += QString::number((int)message.at(i));
    }
    qDebug() << result;
    return result;
}
```

If you want your result to get converted back in ASCII, use

```
QString::toStdString()
```

Use QString instead of regular string when you use Qt Creator, it provides a lot of powerful function